# Electron JS Mac OS X Build Failure with Tray icon in .png format

Tags: electron, electron-packager

For starters my build for a "normal" (non-tray) app works fine with electron-packager and this command

```
npx electron-packager . --overwrite --plaorm=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=aicons/1024.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds
```

I have recently re-factored my code so now is a tray app

so I have

```
  tray = new Tray('icons/elektro.png')
  tray.setToolTip('elektro')
```

This works fine with npm start but when I build the .app using electron-packager I get this error:

```
Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: Error processing argument at index 0, conversion failure from icons/elektro.png
    at App.<anonymous> (/Users/gurugeek/elektro/release-builds/elektro-darwin-x64/elektro.app/Contents/Resources/app/main.js:48:10)
    at App.emit (events.js:205:15)
```

I assume the problem relates to the .png used for the tray icon. If I change it to a .icns format it won't work anymore with npm start.  Any idea how to fix this ?

I am using electron 6

Answer (score 1):

Alright the issue is related to the path. It seems trivial but the .app file just dies without any error in most cases. This issue is very poorly documented everywhere so I leave it here for whomever finds the same issue:

```
  const path = require('path');
  var iconPath = path.join(__dirname, '/icons/elektro.png') // your png tray icon
  let trayIcon = nativeImage.createFromPath(iconPath);
  // if needed resize to 16x16 but mac also accepted the 24 icon
  // trayIcon = trayIcon.resize({
  //    width: 16,
  //    height: 16
  //  });

  tray = new Tray(trayIcon)
```